# how to extract elements from tree.productions()

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, stanford-nlp, context-free-grammar

(1)My goal: To extract left-hand side and right-hand side of a production.

(2)My approach:
I am employing stanford parser and nltk tools to extract parsetree of a sentence. My code is below:

```
corenlp_dir = "/home/corenlp-python/stanford-corenlp-full-2013-11-12/"
parser = corenlp.StanfordCoreNLP(corenlp_path=corenlp_dir)

result_json = json.loads(parser.parse("I have a tree."))
for sentence in result_json["sentences"]:
    t = Tree.fromstring(sentence["parsetree"])
    print t.productions()   # [ROOT -> S, S -> NP VP ., NP -> PRP, PRP -> 'I', VP -> VBP NP, VBP -> 'have', NP -> DT NN, DT -> 'a', NN -> 'tree', . -> '.']

    print t.productions()[1]  # S -> NP VP .
    print type(productions()[1])  # <class 'nltk.grammar.Production'>

    for (i,child) in enumerate(t): 
        print (i,child)  # (0, Tree('S', [Tree('NP', [Tree('PRP', ['I'])]), Tree('VP', [Tree('VBP', ['have']), Tree('NP', [Tree('DT', ['a']), Tree('NN', ['tree'])])]), Tree('.', ['.'])])) I can only get one tree.
```

(3)My question is how I can continue to extract elements from both sides of each **production** , such as **'S'** and **'NP VP .'**. Is there any method can be used to solve this problem?

Could anyone help me and maybe point out some directions?

Comment: Why are you using the `productions` method? It sounds like what you really want to do is traverse the tree. See the [`productions` method](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.html#nltk.tree.Tree.productions) for an example of how to traverse the NLTK `Tree`.

Comment: @JonGauthier What I want to do is to extract both sides of a production object, such as `"S"` and `"NP VP"`.I have read the `productions` methods, but still have no idea on how to traverse the tree correctly.Could you please show me some example code?

Comment: `Tree` instances are iterable. `for child in t: # child is an instance of Tree corresponding to a child of the tree t`

Comment: @JonGauthier Thanks for your reply. after running such code:`t = Tree.fromstring(sentence["parsetree"]) for (i,child) in enumerate(t):
        print (i,child)` I cannot got all the subtrees but one.`(0, Tree('S', [Tree('NP', [Tree('PRP', ['I'])]), Tree('VP', [Tree('VBP', ['have']), Tree('NP', [Tree('DT', ['a']), Tree('NN', ['tree'])])]), Tree('.', ['.'])]))` Could you please show me some details on how to traverse the tree? I really need your help.

Comment: It looks like you have what you need contained within that printout. The `Tree` corresponding to the `S` node has three children, and you can inspect each of their "productions." Maybe look at the code for `Tree.__str__` to see how they're easily accessing these elements? I'm not an NLTK user, so I can't offer much more precise advice than that.

Comment: @JonGauthier Thanks for your kind comments. But what I want to do is to  extract the left-hand side of a production and gather right-hand side of all productions with the same left-hand side. However, I do not think Tree.__str__ will work. Therefore, Could you please give me some idea on how to implement it? I have a hard time with it and really need your help.

Comment: You should restate this problem more clearly in the original SO question / as a separate question—a bit difficult to discuss things in a comment thread, and that way you can draw on the entire NLTK community (not just me)!

Comment: Thank you for your instructions. I have restated this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nltk.Tree` is actually a subclass of the Python `list`, so you can access the children of any node `c` by `c[0]`, `c[1]`, `c[2]`, etc. Note that NLTK trees are not explicitly binary by design, so your notion of "left" and "right" might have to be enforced somewhere in a contract.

Assuming the tree is binary, you can access the left child of a node with `c[0]`, and the right with `c[1]`. For your second task:

> But what I want to do is to extract the left-hand side of a production and gather right-hand side of all productions with the same left-hand side.

If I understand correctly, you can traverse the tree and build up a `dict` as you go, where the keys are left-hand sides and the values are lists of possible right-hand productions. I'm not sure if `nltk.Tree` objects are hashable / immutable (if not, they wouldn't be usable as `dict` keys), but you could use the string form of the `Tree` objects as keys in any case.

Comment: Thanks for your favorable answer. You mean, in this task, I do not need to use `tree.productions()`. Just traversing the tree and using list index to obtain both sides of a production??

Comment: That should be enough, unless you want to account for the entire tree below a particular node rather than just the label of the node itself. If you want to capture the entire subtree under a node, you could store keys as `str(c.productions())`. Again, I'm not certain of your exact intent / application.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My intent is getting a left-hand side and gathering all the right-hand sides from all the productions.for instance, `S -> NP VP, S -> NP ADVP VP, S->  , S-> ...` Is it clear enough to explain my intention? Are you sure I do not need `tree.productions()`?

Comment: Oh! I've been misunderstanding your use of "left hand" and "right hand," thinking you were talking about tree nodes. It sounds like you could easily get this done with a depth-first search that accumulates a dictionary where the keys are the "left-hand sides," then. Something like the structure used in the source for `Tree.productions`.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But `S -> NP VP` is a production object. How can I get both sides of a production? I cannot find any method in the `productions` method. I really need your help

Comment: I'm still not clear on what you mean by "both sides of a production." If you're talking about the left and right child of a tree node, you can access those by indices `c[0]`, `c[1]` as I talked about in my answer. If you mean the left and right side of the arrow, you can do a DFS through the tree (just like they do in `Tree.productions`); each parent you find is the left side of the arrow, and its children are the right side.